# Python Tesseract Returned Nothing, Not Even Empty String

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am running my tesseract on JupyterLab, I took some pain to get the PATH correct according to stackoverflow, and I took some pain to read some questions about tesseract returning empty string, but in my case, my tesseract code does not even return an empty string, there simply is no output.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = Image.open("MP_5x3_080320-236x300.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
text
```

I also tried:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = Image.open("MP_5x3_080320-236x300.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
type(text)
```

to see what type it is for "text" variable, assuming there must be some output, but no. There still is no output even for "type(text)"

exactly what is wrong? can anyone enlighten me?

many thanks!!!

Comment: i tried, it doesnt work. besides, i dont think i need to print in JupyterLab... that's the reason why I specifically mention that i was doing that on JupyterLab...

Comment: shouldn't you give full path to your jpg image when you open that image?

Answer (score 0):

it might be that pytesseract is returning the text string with '\n\x0c' on the end of it (which clears the console). Try

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='-c page_separator=""')
```

You might find more success defining the material with page segmentation as shown here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/05/build-your-own-ocr-google-tesseract-opencv/

example for a single word (single line would be 7 instead of 8)

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 8 -c page_separator=""')
```